# FasterCSV for importing users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastercsv

HI, 
I am trying to use FasterCSV to import users from a CSV file

I have

```
<form action='/users/bulk_create' method='post'>
   <%= file_field_tag "csv_file" %><br/>
   <%= submit_tag("Import") %>
</form>
```

In my users controller i have a method like

```
   def bulk_create
         login, password, name, email = 0, 1, 2, 3
     require 'fastercsv'
          parsed_rows=FasterCSV.parse(params[:csv_file])
           parsed_rows.each do |row|
            puts "#{row[name]}"
           end
   end
```

When i do the above and inspect it in the log i am getting the error as

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `pos' for nil:NilClass):
 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:688:in `bulk_create'
```

FasterCsv is not reading the file at all. 
How to make it to read
      I installed the gem using sudo gem install fastercsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are uploading a file, you must specify the `enctype` attribute for your form as `multipart/form-data`

```
<form action='/users/bulk_create' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Secondly you cannot pass `params[:csv_file]` directly to FasterCSV, you need to sanity check the data and then save it as a csv file.

Have a look here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm which gives the basics of file uploading. I would strongly suggest looking at file upload plugin like "[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)" or the likes.

Then after you have saved the file, and the docs for "FasterCSV" suggest

```
#Reading
#From a File
#A Line at a Time

FasterCSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

Comment: Why write the file to the disk? Processing it on-the-fly would improve performance (no disk IO) and reduce the security risks.

Answer (score 1):

It also works:

```
@rows = []
uploaded_io = params[:csv_file]
FCSV.new(uploaded_io.tempfile).each do |row|
 @rows << row
end
```